# how to check comma between two string and build a regex for that

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box and I need to have validation that no commas allowed between two words like this given below eg B521,Baraghat. I want to have regext for that. How to do that in javascript.

Comment: no commas between words, or no commas at all in your textbox?

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\,/g , "");`

Answer (score 0):

A regex is not necessary for this check.  This will make sure that your string does not contain a comma.

```
if(str.indexOf(',') != -1) {
     <Invalid string logic>
}
```

If you insist on a regex:

```
if(str.match(/\,/)) {
     <invalid string logic>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var patt=/[^,]+,[^,]+/
```

That will find a comma between two non-commas.

This matches both:

> B521,Baraghat

and

> B521 , Baraghat

If you want to find a comma between two words explicitly, you can do:

```
var patt=/\b,\b/
```

This will find a comma between two word boundaries.

This matches

> B521,Baraghat

but not

> B521 , Baraghat